# Appending to dictionary of [character: [object]] returns 0 key/value pair

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to show a tableview similar to contacts with my list of users.

I declare a global variable of friends that will store the first character of a name and a list of users whose first name start with that

```
var friends = [Character: [User]]()
```

In my fetch method, I do this

```
for friend in newFriends {                      
    let letter = friend.firstName?[(friend.firstName?.startIndex)!]
    print(letter)                    
    self.friends[letter!]?.append(friend)
}
```

After this, I should have my friends array with the first letter of the name and the users that fall in it; however, my friends dictionary is empty.

How do I fix this?

Edit: I'm following this tutorial and he doesnt exactly the same.. [Swift: How to make alphabetically section headers in table view with a mutable data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521556/swift-how-to-make-alphabetically-section-headers-in-table-view-with-a-mutable-d)

Comment: How is your `User` class defined? Is `firstName` an optional String?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt yeah optional string! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `Character` as the key, use `String`.  You need to be sure to init the `[User]` array for every new First Initial key you insert into `groupedNames`.  I keep an array of `groupedLetters` to make it easier to get a section count

```
var groupedNames = [String: [User]]()
var groupedLetters = Array<String>()

func filterNames() {
    groupedNames.removeAll()
    groupedLetters.removeAll()

    for friend in newFriends {
        let index = friend.firstName.index(friend.firstName.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let firstLetter = String(friend.firstName[index]).uppercased()
        if groupedNames[firstLetter] != nil {
            //array already exists, just append
            groupedNames[firstLetter]?.append(friend)
        } else {
            //no array for that letter key - init array and store the letter in the groupedLetters array
            groupedNames[firstLetter] = [friend]
            groupedLetters.append(firstLetter)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Can't believe I missed that lol! appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `Dictionary` structure with `Characters` as `keys` & values as `Array` of `User` will be more succinct.

Comment: Is this not exactly what I'm doing? I might have misunderstood your statement. @ystack

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are declaring an **empty** dictionary, that means you have to add a key / empty array pair if there is no entry for that character.

Consider also to consolidate the question / exclamation marks

```
class User {
    let firstName : String

    init(firstName : String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
    }
}


var friends = [Character: [User]]()

let newFriends = [User(firstName:"foo"), User(firstName:"bar"), User(firstName:"baz")]

for friend in newFriends {
    let letter = friend.firstName[friend.firstName.startIndex]
    if friends[letter] == nil {
        friends[letter] = [User]()
    }
    friends[letter]!.append(friend)
}
```